# Retrieving console log from Firefox 43 with Selenium without Firefox extensions

Tags: javascript, java, firefox, selenium, console.log

Is it possible to retrieve the browsers console.log with Selenium and Firefox 43? If so, how?

Here are my settings:

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
LoggingPreferences logs = new LoggingPreferences();
logs.enable(LogType.BROWSER, Level.ALL);
logs.enable(LogType.DRIVER, Level.ALL);
logs.enable(LogType.CLIENT, Level.ALL);
logs.enable(LogType.PERFORMANCE, Level.ALL);
logs.enable(LogType.PROFILER, Level.ALL);
logs.enable(LogType.SERVER, Level.ALL);
capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.LOGGING_PREFS, logs);

FirefoxBinary binary = new FirefoxBinary(new File(...));
FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(binary, profile, capabilities);

//...doing things with the driver ...

driver.manage().logs().get(LogType.BROWSER) // already tried every LogType
```

The only output i get from this is something like:

```
1450878255029   addons.xpi  DEBUG   startup
...
Error in parsing value for 'display'.  Declaration dropped.
```

But not the output which is written in the browsers javascript console log.

I already tried several FF profile settings like:

```
profile.setPreference("extensions.sdk.console.logLevel", "all");
profile.setPreference("webdriver.log.file",tempfile.getAbsolutePath());
profile.setPreference("webdriver.firefox.logfile", othertempfile.getAbsolutePath());
profile.setPreference("webdriver.log.driver", "ALL");
```

Nothing helped so far.
In Chrome this is working flawlessly.

Selenium version: 2.48.2
Firefox version: 43.0.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue. I only got all that log noise about css, security, network and what not, but not what was actually logged by the app through `console.log`. I am using the same version for webdriver and firefox you do. For other browsers this was not a problem.

I ended up extending my client code with custom log recording. Speaking in wire protocol terms:

- use `execute` to put something like the following into the client

```js
window.recordedLogs = [];

console.log = function (message) {

    if (typeof message === 'object') {
        message = JSON.stringify(message);
    }

    window.recordedLogs.push(message);
};
```

- use `execute` to retrieve `window.recordedLogs`

Warning: the above code is very simplistic, it does not take care of multiple messages passed to the log method, nor does it handle other log methods like info, error, etc.

However it can be a good multi-browser-compliant alternative to the wire protocol `log` method.

Comment: Question: how do you make sure that this code is actually injected into each page, if you're testing a multi-page flow?
That's what I'm struggling with